# Using a custom authentication mechanism with SSH

Tags: ssh, hsm

I have a hardware device that can compute ECDSA signatures and generate ECDSA keys without exporting the private key (only public key is exported).

I'm looking for a way to tie this into SSH. Is there a way to do so without patching OpenSSH?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a PAM authentication plugin.

Comment: PAM, aka Pluggable Authentication Modules are the answer to the question.